# Can't Run a Crontab program?

Tags: cron

I'm just trying to run a simple python script once daily in crontab but can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
48 23 * * * cd ~ /downloads/nextfolder/script.py
```

That's what I'm currently working with but it could be completely off. What's the right syntax for running a python3 script on a Mac?